# How to use keyDown in NSObjectController

Tags: macos, keydown, xcode5.1, nsobjectcontroller

I'm developing an ap for MacOSX with Xcode5

my initial window is NSObjectController based, and I'm trying to capture keyboard events by using the common method I used on NSWindowControllers called

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{}
```

but this doesn't captures anything... is there any other method for such task????

thanks in advance for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's another way to get it work on NSObjectController...

this captures left key and right key for instance....

```
@interface MyNSObjectController(){
    id          eventMonitor; 
}

@end

@implementation MyNSObjectController
- (void) awakeFromNib{
    [self captureKeyDownEvents];
}

-(void)captureKeyDownEvents{
    NSEvent  *(^handler)(NSEvent*)  = ^(NSEvent *theEvent) {
        NSObjectController *targetWindow          = self;
        if (targetWindow != self) {
            return theEvent;
        }

        NSEvent *result = theEvent;
        if (theEvent.keyCode == 123) { //left arrow
            NSLog(@"you just pressed left key");
            result = nil;
        }

        if (theEvent.keyCode == 124) { //right arrow
            NSLog(@"you just pressed right key");
            result = nil;
        }

        return result;
    };
    eventMonitor = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:handler];
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [NSEvent removeMonitor:eventMonitor];
}

@end
```